# Error: 0x80370114 when installing Ubuntu in windows

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

Good evening, in January I installed Ubuntu via the Windows/Linux system and I had no trouble whatsoever. Sadly I had a problem with the screen and my PC (Asus RGE G14) was reset and I had to install everything once again, however this time after installing WSL I can't get Ubuntu to install.

The image says it all, but it says the installation is starting and then the error appears saying "the operation was not successfully initiated because a necessary function isn't installed", honestly I don't understand why, I'm not very good with computers specially working within the files and system I followed a lot of guides to fix the problem and all were in vain, besides Hyper-V not showing up on my PC even though I searched everywhere the guides told me where to find, I can't find anything that is blocking the installation of Ubuntu. I'm a bit desperate because I have a project I have to do and exams are coming and without Ubuntu working I can't study properly.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your Windows installation has WSL1 and you're trying to install a version of Ubuntu that requires WSL2. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768646/14952832) will walk you through the steps of getting your system reconfigured 